# MySQL don't want to store unicode character

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf8mb4

Why won't MySQL store the unicode character ? Yes, it is a rare hieroglyph, you wouldn't see it in the browser.
UTF16 is `U+2B5EE`

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xAB\x97\xAE' for column 'ch' at row 1
```

Is it possible to store this character in MySQL?

Comment: you may want to check this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14052 it seemed related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MySQL` only supports characters from the basic multilingual plane (`0x0000` - `0xFFFF`).

Your character is out if this plane.

Try storing a synonym instead :)

**Update:**

`MySQL 5.5.3` and on (which has not gone GA yet) does support supplementary characters if you use [`UTF8MB4` encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Comment: Have had troubles with utf8 in MySQL for days. Now I know why! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First: your statement

> UTF16 is U+2B5EE

is slightly wrong. `U+2B5EE` is the notation for a Unicode *codepoint*, just a integer number- an abstract code- while UTF16 is a charset encoding (one of possible Unicode encodings, as is UTF-8).

Now, assuming that you mean the codepoint, `U+2B5EE` is outside the BMP (first 64K unicode codepoints), and it seems mysql have [little or no support for them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html). So I suspect you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, MySQL 5.5.3 was released which supports the `utf8mb4` encoding which offers full Unicode support. Switching to this charset instead of `utf8` would fix your problem.

I’ve recently written [**a detailed guide on how to switch from MySQL’s `utf8` to `utf8mb4`**](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4). If you follow the steps there, everything should work correctly. Here are direct links to each individual step in the process:

- [Step 1: Create a backup](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#backup)
- [Step 2: Upgrade the MySQL server](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#upgrade)
- [Step 3: Modify databases, tables, and columns](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#databases-tables-columns)
- [Step 4: Check the maximum length of columns and index keys](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#column-index-length)
- [Step 5: Modify connection, client, and server character sets](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets)
- [Step 6: Repair and optimize all tables](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#repair-optimize)

I suspect that your problem can be solved by following step 5. Hope this helps!