# Can't insert a unicode glyph in mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

With this query:

```
UPDATE  `arg`.`arg_currency` SET  `symbol` =  '' WHERE  `arg_currency`.`id` =2 LIMIT 1 ;
```

I get this error:

> Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value:
>   '\xF0\x90\x80\xA4' for column 'symbol'
>   at row 1

The column `symbol` was a `CHAR(1)` `utf8_roman_ci`, but I've both tried to change the collation to _general and to _unicode, and the chars to 4, but I've still got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

(I've both tried to insert it via custom php code and via phpmyadmin)

Comment: Where does the character come from?

Comment: @Pekka: it's a Linear B character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10024/index.htm

Comment: @Lo yeah, just found it myself. Strange, looks like a perfectly fine utf-8 character to me. Can you try setting the type to `varchar`? Just to exclude the possibility

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692188/mysql-dont-want-to-store-unicode-charecter

Comment: @Carpe that solves it. Voting to close as duplicate

Comment: @Carpe @Pekka: oh, true. Still unclear to me how to solve that, though...

Comment: @Lo:  What is your frontend?   Have the frontend/app convert it to a number and then store the number... Then encode it when you retrieve it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @CarpeNoctumDC points out, this question explains the problem:

[MySQL don't want to store unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692188/mysql-dont-want-to-store-unicode-charecter)

> MySQL only supports characters from the basic multilingual plane (0x0000 - 0xFFFF).
>
> Your character is out if this plane.

In your case, I would work around it by storing the character as a numeric entity. <strike>[`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) with the UTF-8 encoding specified should be able to entity it, for example.</strike> no, it doesn't.

[This function in the User Contributed Notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#96648) of the PHP manual works for me: It converts the character into a numeric entity.

```
echo utf8tohtml("", true); // echoes &#65572;
```

Comment: Oh even better, I'll just store it as a 4 byte unsigned int then! Thanks :)

Comment: +1: But my actual reaction is WHAAT!? Doesn't MySQL support characters from any of the 16 supplementary planes? Ah, saw now that MySQL 5.5 and later supports UTF-16 and UTF-8. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: @dalle yeah, I'm baffled too! And I can't see a real reason for this, either.

Answer (score -1):

this `''` in what encoding is?? first try to convert from your encoding to mysql table encoding in php using `iconv()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

UPDATE:

it looks like the `''` was encoded on the fly to string `\xF0\x90\x80\xA4`,
if your field is CHAR(1) it don't fit and return error - neeed to find why it is encoded.

Comment: It's a valid UTF-8 character: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280&number=512

Comment: @Dobiatowski nope: A UTF-8 char(1) will hold one UTF-8 character, i.e. up to 4 bytes. Also the OP states he already tried setting the field's width to 4

Comment: @Pekka but i suppose when you change the field type to varchar(16) it will be saved but not as UTF char but as string of encoded symbol

Comment: @Dobiatowski I don't think so - why would it? It would be nice though if it did. Apparently, there's no way to store those characters natively. (See the duplicate)

Comment: @Pekka you have right, i though that it was encoded to the string.