# Why some special unicode word make mysql can not update a table?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL don't want to store unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692188/mysql-dont-want-to-store-unicode-character)

I writing a bbs php code, user reply something with some special unicode word, and I find my mysql code can not work.
`var_dump` it, the sql look like:

[image]

I use a Mac mysql client Sequel Pro, run this code, it said that:

> No errors;0 rows affected.

But when remove the word "kiss", it said that:

> No errors;1 rows affected.

Do you know why? And how I solve it?

Please notice, this user input is already process by `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Have you tried to use `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` after you connected to the db?

Comment: already mysql_set_charset('utf8'); ...

Comment: Also try `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Comment: already mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Ok. What codepoint has the kiss? Is it outside of the BMP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692188/mysql-dont-want-to-store-unicode-character

Comment: Yes, it is like this. but I do not want upgrade to mysql 5.5, and find some way now.

Comment: Well, as @some doesn't seem to be willing to write it as an answer, at least it have to be marked as a duplicate. However, I doubt it will get enough votes, so it would be nice to add the link to the question manually.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It's not that I didn't want to write an answer, but more that I needed more information. Now it's clear that it's a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Escape query string first then feed it to SQL statement. PHP has [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

If `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't work, then you may want to use prepare statements instead to avoid the issue entirely, like so:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

The above example is quoted from [PHP document](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: In fact, this line is after mysql_real_escape_string ...

Comment: I am curious, have you got an example of at least one bug mysql_real_escape_string has?

Comment: It is not about mysql_real_escape_string , is about mysql 5.5 and utf8mb4.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, say numeric values and whitespace? But yeah it is documented. My apologies for going too far to call it a bug. Edited.