# Emoticons from iPhone to Python/Django

Tags: iphone, python, django, emoticons

I'm trying to save comments from an iPhone app that may and nowadays most likely *will* include emoticons. No matter what I do, I can't save the emoticons to the MySQL database ... Constant Unicode errors.

- Python 2.6.5
- Django 1.2.1
- MySQL database (set to utf8 character set for tables and rows)
- Saving the data to a VARCHAR(255) field

The error I keep receiving is:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x97\xBC \xF0...' for column 'body' at row 1
```

The string I'm passing into the database is:

```
test_txt = u"Emoji - \U0001f5fc \U0001f60c \U0001f47b ...".encode('utf-8')
```

**Update**: Here's the model I'm using:

```
class ItemComment(db.Model):
  item = db.ForeignKey(Item)
  user = db.ForeignKey(Profile)
  body = db.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

  active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
  date_added = db.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.item)
```

The odd thing is, if I try and pass this to a field that I've created in MySQL and not Django models.py it works fine. But as soon as I register the field in Django models it dies. Is there another way to store these perhaps?

Any ideas would be amazing.
I could not be more stuck on this ...

**Update 2**: Tracking it in Terminal using the following UPDATE statement (notice the U0001f5fc)

```
UPDATE 'table' SET 'body' = '', WHERE 'table'.'id' = 1 ; args=(u'\U0001f5fc')
```

Using as hardcore as I can get to pass the value:

```
force_unicode(smart_str(value), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='ignore')
```

But the error still throws:

```
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x97\xBC' for column 'body' at row 1
```

Totally lost!!!

Cheers,

Comment: Could you provide your model?

Comment: @bossylobster, cheers, just added the model to the copy above.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django, since you said it works fine in MySQL I doubt this will hope, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @bossylobster, no idea why as it seems to help the other folks. But I receive the exact same error. From the look of things, the DB is set up as utf8 all the way. Thanks though ...

Comment: Did you create the tables after setting the db to utf8? I believe with postgres at least, encoding changes only apply to new tables

Comment: @cberner, no go. Just DROPped some tables, CREATEd them again, making sure "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" and no dice. I'm gonna update everything to the latest and see how we go. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

Change charset utf8mb4 for MySQL server (version 5.5.3 later)

In `my.ini` (`my.cnf`)

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

or SQL query

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
```

see also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html

or deletes the character to do it.

python

```
import re
# emoji_text is unicode
no_emoji_text = re.sub('[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]', '', str(emoji_text))
```

Thank you.

See also
[MySQL throws Incorrect string value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709892/mysql-throws-incorrect-string-value-error)

Comment: This is also the solution I used. If that might help I wrote an article where I tried to explain the problems I had, which were similar : http://pjambet.github.io/blog/emojis-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I use Django 1.11 and following `setting.py` and the create `sql` can store emoji well,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},   # note here!!!
    }
}
```

The `sql` come from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76788/create-a-database-with-charset-utf-8/76789#76789) answer,

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```