# Doctrine2 not saving utf-8

Tags: symfony, utf-8, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony 2 app my Doctrine charset is set to `UTF8`.

I have this string which starts with 
Using mb_detect_encoding it's UTF-8.

But saving it into a text field on a Doctrine entity gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8C\\xB9 h...' for column 'text' at row 1",
```

What the hell is happening here?

Comment: how looks MySQL encoding configuration in `my.cnf`, sections `[mysql]` and `[mysqld`]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you what is happening. The database engine is unable to store the string value \xF0\x9F\x8C\xB9 in the database.

That appears to be the character [U+1F339 ROSE](http://codepoints.net/U+1F339) which is in the supplementary multi-lingual plane and takes 4 bytes to store.

MySQL UTF8 doesn't actually support all of UTF8, and basically doesn't work at all for 4 byte characters. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709892/mysql-throws-incorrect-string-value-error/8767381#8767381) for suggestions on how to fix it but basically you need to switch to use the 'utf8mb4' charset everywhere with the collation 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' if you want to store these characters.

Comment: So for that I need MySQL version 5.5.3? It won't work on 5.1.50?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that is correct. Without desperation measures like switching the column to binary, there's no way to insert a 4 byte utf8 character into a 'utf8' column prior to 5.5.3

Comment: Is it possible to use a NoSQL database solution to bypass this problem of utf8 in MySQL?

Comment: Completely changing technology to solve a small problem is a bad idea. Just change the tables to use utf8mb4 as the char set will take 10 minutes and completely solve the problem.