# Mysql four byte chinese characters support

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I can't execute this SQL script:

```
INSERT INTO `mabase`.`new_table` (`idnew_table`, `name`) VALUES ('2', '');
```

the error is:

> ERROR 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA0\xBC\xAD' for column 'name' at row 1
>   SQL Statement:
>   INSERT INTO `mabase`.`new_table` (`idnew_table`, `name`) VALUES ('2', '')

My database and table is in utf8 charset and utf8_general_ci collation.
Also i tried:
utf8_unicode_ci,
utf8mb4_general_ci,
bg5_cinese_ci,
gbk_cinese_ci.

I've tried all that in MySql workbench
on windows.

is four byte character. I have problems only with them.
Tell me Please how can I save four byte character in mysql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL throws Incorrect string value error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709892/mysql-throws-incorrect-string-value-error)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your desired character, [U+20F2D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20f2d/), resides in the "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B" block of Unicode's "Supplementary Ideographic Plane" and therefore was not available in any MySQL Unicode character set prior to v5.5; since v5.5, it is available in the [`utf8mb4`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html), [`utf16`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf16.html), [`utf16le`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf16le.html) and [`utf32`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf32.html) character sets.

It is not available in MySQL's `big5` or `gbk` character sets.

---

#### Why the `utf8` encoding does not work

As documented under [Unicode Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode.html):

> The initial implementation of Unicode support (in MySQL 4.1) included two character sets for storing Unicode data:
>
> - `ucs2`, the UCS-2 encoding of the Unicode character set using 16 bits per character.
> - `utf8`, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character.
>
> These two character sets support the characters from the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) of Unicode Version 3.0. BMP characters have these characteristics:
>
> - Their code values are between 0 and 65535 (or `U+0000` .. `U+FFFF`).
> - They can be encoded with a fixed 16-bit word, as in `ucs2`.
> - They can be encoded with 8, 16, or 24 bits, as in `utf8`.
> - They are sufficient for almost all characters in major languages.
>
> Characters not supported by the aforementioned character sets include supplementary characters that lie outside the BMP. Characters outside the BMP compare as REPLACEMENT CHARACTER and convert to `'?'` when converted to a Unicode character set.
>
> In MySQL 5.6, Unicode support includes supplementary characters, which requires new character sets that have a broader range and therefore take more space. The following table shows a brief feature comparison of previous and current Unicode support.
>
> ```
> ╔══════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
> ║       Before MySQL 5.5       ║              MySQL 5.5 and up                ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ All Unicode 3.0 characters   ║ All Unicode 5.0 and 6.0 characters           ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ No supplementary characters  ║ With supplementary characters                ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ ucs2 character set, BMP only ║ No change                                    ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ utf8 character set for up to ║ No change                                    ║
> ║ three bytes, BMP only        ║                                              ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║                              ║ New utf8mb4 character set for up to four     ║
> ║                              ║ bytes, BMP or supplemental                   ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║                              ║ New utf16 character set, BMP or supplemental ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║                              ║ New utf16le character set, BMP or            ║
> ║                              ║ supplemental (5.6.1 and up)                  ║
> ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║                              ║ New utf32 character set, BMP or supplemental ║
> ╚══════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
> ```
>
> These changes are upward compatible. If you want to use the new character sets, there are potential incompatibility issues for your applications; see [Section 10.1.11, “Upgrading from Previous to Current Unicode Support”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html). That section also describes how to convert tables from `utf8` to the (4-byte) `utf8mb4` character set, and what constraints may apply in doing so.

#### Why the `big5` encoding does not work

As documented under [What problems should I be aware of when working with the Big5 Chinese character set?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-B-11-1-3):

> MySQL supports the Big5 character set which is common in Hong Kong and Taiwan (Republic of China). MySQL's `big5` is in reality Microsoft code page 950, which is very similar to the original `big5` character set.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> A feature request for adding `HKSCS` extensions has been filed. People who need this extension may find the suggested patch for Bug #13577 to be of interest.

#### Why the `gbk` encoding does not work

As documented under [What CJK character sets are available in MySQL?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-B-11-1-1):

> Here, we try to clarify exactly what characters are legitimate in `gb2312` or `gbk`, with reference to the official documents. Please check these references before reporting `gb2312` or `gbk` bugs.
>
> - For a complete listing of the `gb2312` characters, ordered according to the `gb2312_chinese_ci` collation: [gb2312](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/by-charset.html#gb2312)
> - MySQL's `gbk` is in reality “Microsoft code page 936”. This differs from the official `gbk` for characters `A1A4` (middle dot), `A1AA` (em dash), `A6E0-A6F5`, and `A8BB-A8C0`.
> - For a listing of `gbk`/Unicode mappings, see http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP936.TXT.
> - For MySQL's listing of `gbk` characters, see [gbk](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/by-charset.html#gbk).

Comment: Hello Thanks for so good answer, but i steel need help.
I've tried this script on server 5.5 and 5.7 alpha and it fails:
CREATE SCHEMA `new_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ;
CREATE  TABLE `new_schema`.`new_table` (
  `idnew_table` INT NOT NULL ,
  `new_tablecol` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnew_table`) )
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `new_schema`.`new_table` (`idnew_table`, `new_tablecol`) VALUES ('1', ''); 
I've execute it from workbench.

Comment: @yaroslavprokipchyn: I think you'll find it's Workbench that can't cope with supplementary characters. I believe it uses UTF-8 internally and so sets `utf8` as the [charset of its database connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) (even though it probably can support `utf8mb4`, which suggests this is likely a bug) and this is why MySQLd is complaining that the received string is invalid. You could try `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';`, but Workbench may not like you trying to override its expected character set. Otherwise `INSERT INTO new_table VALUES (1, _utf8mb4'');`.

Comment: A great answer with rich reference, surely deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

### These 2 commands will support chinese charachters in your database.

> ALTER DATABASE  CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE
>   'utf8_unicode_ci'
>
> ALTER TABLE  convert to character set DEFAULT COLLATE
>   DEFAULT

Short and simple.

hope it helps