# Other Language(Chinese) character chenge in to ??????? Mysql Load Query

Tags: mysql, csv, file-encodings, mysql-loadfile

I have a `csv` File in that few columns are containing Chinese words,
I am uploading the csv file in Mysql Table using Query:

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '/CsvFile.csv' INTO TABLE mytableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

after upload the Chinese characters are getting change into `????????` in `mysql` table.
why this is happening? and is there any solution.

Thanks:)

Comment: Which charset and collate have you set in MySQL? The default will not cover Chinese characters. I think UTF-8 will cover simplified Chinese, not sure what you need if you are including traditional

Comment: You need to set encoding with utf8  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680237/mysql-four-byte-chinese-characters-support