# Openshift MySQL UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, jboss7.x, openshift

**I got problem to insert String with correct UTF-8 encoding to MySQL database.** The String is not inserted correctly. I found many solutions of this problem on web, but nothing works well for me on Openshift. I´m able to insert it corectly at my local server, but not at cloud configuration. Here is my problem:

From EJB I´m inserting: Příliš žluťoučký kůň pěl ďábelské ódy

but at MySQL is stored: P?�li? ?lu?ou?k� k?? p?l ?�belsk� �

**I use PaaS cloud Openshift, JBoss Application server 7, MySQL 5.5**

here is my code:

1. MySQL: database, tables and colums have set correct collation: utf8_czech_ci

   mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';

> ```
> Variable_name                 Value
>
> character_set_client          utf8
>
> character_set_connection      utf8
>
> character_set_database        utf8
>
> character_set_filesystem      binary
>
> character_set_results         utf8
>
> character_set_server          utf8
>
> character_set_system          utf8
>
> character_sets_dir            /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/share/mysql/charsets
> ```

2.jsp

```
  <form role="form" method="post" action="MakeRezervationServlet">
                    <input type="hidden" name="term" value="${param.termin}"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userName">Startovní lokace</label>
                        <input type="text" name="startLocation"  value="U autoskoly" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userName">Poznámka</label>
                        <input type="text" name="note"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Zde můžete zanechat vzkaz pro instruktora" >
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Potvrdit termín</button>
```

3.Servlet. I found by testing, that String is OK in Servlet, there is not problem between Servlet and jsp

```
 package application.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import application.ejb.RezervationLocal;


@WebServlet("/MakeRezervationServlet")
public class MakeRezervationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
private RezervationLocal rezervation;

public MakeRezervationServlet() {
    super();     
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String note = request.getParameter("note");
    byte[] n = note.getBytes("ISO8859_1");
    note = new String(n, "UTF-8");

    String startLocation = request.getParameter("startLocation");
    byte[] startLoc = startLocation.getBytes("ISO8859_1");
    startLocation = new String(startLoc, "UTF-8");

    String term = request.getParameter("term");
    int idTerm = Integer.valueOf(term);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String IDuser;
    int intIDuser;

    synchronized (session) {
        IDuser = (String) session.getAttribute("IDuser");
        intIDuser = Integer.valueOf(IDuser);
    }

    //hardcode předává konstantního instruktora id=3
    String message = rezervation.makeRezervation(idTerm, intIDuser, 3, startLocation, note);
    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("kalendar.jsp").forward(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
```

}

1. EJB. I found by testing that also in EJB is String still OK

   ```
   package application.ejb;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException; 
   import javax.annotation.Resource;
   import javax.ejb.EJB;
   import javax.ejb.Stateless;
   import javax.sql.DataSource;
   import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
   import javax.ejb.Stateless;
   import javax.naming.Context;
   import javax.naming.InitialContext;

   @Stateless
   @LocalBean
   public class Rezervation implements RezervationLocal {

   @EJB
   private LoggerBeanLocal loggerBean;
   @EJB
   private UtilityBeanLocal utilityBean;

   public Rezervation() {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   @Override
   public String makeRezervation(int idTerm, int idStudent, int idInstructor, String startLocation, String note) {
       String message = "";
       Connection conn = null;
       PreparedStatement stat = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;

       try {
           try {
               conn = connect();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           synchronized (conn) {
               stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ID_TERM FROM TBL_TERMS WHERE ID_STUDENT = ? AND ID_TYPE_OF_STATUS <= 2 ORDER BY ID_TERM");
               stat.setInt(1, idStudent);
               rs = stat.executeQuery();

               Boolean podminka1 = false;
               Boolean podminka2 = false;

               int counter = 0;
               String term2 = String.valueOf(idTerm);
               term2 = term2.substring(0, 8);
               String term;

               while (rs.next()) {

                   term = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ID_TERM"));
                   term = term.substring(0, 8);
                   if (term.equals(term2)) {
                       podminka1 = true;
                   }

                   counter++;
                   if (counter == 14) {
                       podminka2 = true;
                   }

               }
               if (podminka1) {
                   message = "Nelze rezervovat více jízd ve stejný den.";
               } else if (podminka2) {
                   message = "Nelze rezervovat více jízd. Již máte absolvováno nebo rezervováno všech 14 jízd.";
               } else {

                   stat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TBL_TERMS (ID_TERM, ID_STUDENT, ID_INSTRUCTOR, START_LOCATION, NOTE, ID_TYPE_OF_STATUS) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                   stat.setInt(1, idTerm);
                   stat.setInt(2, idStudent);
                   stat.setInt(3, idInstructor);
                   stat.setString(4, startLocation);
                   stat.setString(5, note);
                   stat.setInt(6, 1);
                   stat.execute();
                   String date = utilityBean.parseDate(idTerm);
                   message = "Termín " + date + " byl uložen";
                   loggerBean.log(idStudent, "made rezervation "+idTerm);
               }
           }

       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           message = "Termín nebyl uložen: " + ex.toString();

       } finally {

           try {
               if (rs != null) {
                   rs.close();
               }
               if (stat != null) {
                   stat.close();
               }
               if (conn != null) {
                   conn.close();
               }
           } catch (SQLException e) {
           }
       }
       return message;
   }

    public Connection connect() throws Exception {
       String jndiName = "java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS";
       Connection con = null;
       Context ic = new InitialContext();
       Object obj = ic.lookup(jndiName);
       javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) obj;
       con = ds.getConnection();        
       return con;
   }
   ```

   }

5.standalone.xml -I use in jdbc url //...?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" enabled="${mysql.enabled}" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MysqlDS" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                  <user-name>${xxx}</user-name>
                  <password>${exxx}</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
                    <!--<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>-->
                </validation>
                <pool>
                                <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                        </pool>
            </datasource>
```

Any help appreciate. I have already spent a lot of time about solving this issue. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL throws Incorrect string value error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709892/mysql-throws-incorrect-string-value-error)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this forum post and see if it helps any: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/mysql-encoding-problem-in-jboss-application