# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8F' for column 'tweetcontent' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, twitter

I try to save twitter feeds in mysql database  in the following table

```
 CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tweetcontent` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

but the following error has appeared

```
            java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8F'
                             for column  'tweetcontent' at row 1
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This post is useful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709892/mysql-throws-incorrect-string-value-error

Answer (score 5):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959780/3085520)

MySQL's `utf8` permits only the Unicode characters that can be represented with 3 bytes in UTF-8. Here you have a character that needs 4 bytes: \xF0\x90\x8D\x83 ([U+10343 GOTHIC LETTER SAUIL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10343/index.htm)).

If you have MySQL 5.5 or later you can change the column encoding from `utf8` to [`utf8mb4`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html). This encoding allows storage of characters that occupy 4 bytes in UTF-8.

You may also have to set the server property `character_encoding_server` to `utf8mb4` in the MySQL configuration file. It seems that [Connector/J defaults to 3-byte Unicode otherwise](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html):

> For example, to use 4-byte UTF-8 character sets with Connector/J, configure the MySQL server with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`, and leave `characterEncoding` out of the Connector/J connection string. Connector/J will then autodetect the UTF-8 setting.